# find_by on unsaved many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a model Payment which has many PaymentItems where each payment item is associated with an Item.

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payment_items, inverse_of: :payment
  has_many :items, through: :payment_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :payment_items, reject_if: ->(payment_item_attributes) { payment_item_attributes['item_id'].blank? }
  ...
end

class PaymentItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tab_item, inverse_of: :payment_item
  belongs_to :payment, inverse_of: :payment_items

  ... validations ...
end
```

In my form for a payment, I'm using a fields_for method for each PaymentItem while iterating over available items.

```
= form_for @payment do |f|
  - @tab_items.each do |item|
    = f.fields_for :payment_items, @payment.payment_items.find_or_initialize_by(item_id: item.id) do |payment_item_form|
      %label
        = payment_item_form.check_box :item_id, item.id, nil
        = item.name
```

There is more nesting going on to collect more information for payment_item which has validations but if validations fail find_or_initialize_by method does not find items by item_id.

My question is: does find_by work on unpersisted nested models in case validation fails? My work around for now is to do something like:

```
@payment.payment_items.select {|i| i.tab_item_id == item.id } || @payment.payment_items.new(tab_item: item)
```

but it feels clunky.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Payment.joins( :payment_items => :item ).where( :payment_items => {:tab_item_id => item.id}, :payment_items  => {:name => "something"} )` you can try something like this , you can get any number of information on payment_items as I passed `name`

Comment: Another thing is that I also want to retain the validation errors in those nested models, with this solution I think I would lose them everytime the form is re-rendered

Comment: Why don't you keep your child validations on child model